# Using php as a crutch for toggling variables in D3-- there must be a better way

Tags: d3.js

I've got a D3 streamflow visualization that enables users to toggle between 9 watersheds and view raw streamflow data, 'high' and 'low' flow events (red & yellow dots), and the estimated threshold for high events (red line):

http://forestecoservices.net/FESTvisualizations/HubbardBrook/streamflow.html

The data source is a PostgreSQL database with the data in this (relatively standard) configuration, shown here as csv:

date,ws_1,ws_2,ws_3,ws_4,ws_5,ws_6,ws_7,ws_8,ws_9
1/1/2000,40,0.541,0.57,0.605,0.643,0.594,0.456,0.299,0.206
1/2/2000,0.739,0.576,0.594,0.654,0.74,0.625,0.44,0.313,0.224

The only problem is I couldn't figure out how to feed the variable names into D3, .. I found some examples, but they all have the data set up this way:

> date, watershed, value
>
> 1/1/2000, ws_1, 40
>
> 1/1/2000, ws_2, 0.541

etc.

It might not be pretty, but I knew I could fake it with php, so I made a combobox that calls a php script that queries the database and spits out a json, which is then used by d3 to redraw the graph.  (I also haven't quite figured out how to get the dots to move too, but that's another story).  I KNOW there must be a (better) way to do this natively in d3 without having to resort to php.

Any advice much appreciated!

Steve Signell

Here's my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body { font: 12px Arial;}

path {
stroke: steelblue;
stroke-width: 2;
fill: none;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
fill: none;
stroke: grey;
stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.grid .tick {
stroke: lightgrey;
opacity: 0.9;
}
.grid path {
stroke-width: 0.1;
}

div.tooltip {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
width: 80px;
height: 28px;
padding: 2px;
font: 11px sans-serif;
background: lightsteelblue;
border: 0px;
border-radius: 18px;
pointer-events: none;
}

</style>

<body>

<div id="option">
<select type='select' onchange='updateData(value);' style='color:red;font-size:1.3em;'>
   <option value='ws_1' name='ws_1' selected='true' >Watershed 1</option>
   <option value='ws_2' name='ws_2'>Watershed 2</option>
   <option value='ws_3' name='ws_3'>Watershed 3</option>
   <option value='ws_4' name='ws_4'>Watershed 4</option> 
   <option value='ws_5' name='ws_5'>Watershed 5</option>
   <option value='ws_6' name='ws_6'>Watershed 6</option>
   <option value='ws_7' name='ws_7'>Watershed 7</option> 
   <option value='ws_8' name='ws_8'>Watershed 8</option>
   <option value='ws_9' name='ws_9'>Watershed 9</option>
</select>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width =800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 420 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;
var formatTime = d3.time.format("%e %b %Y");

var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(10);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

//create line of stream flow values
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    //.interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.flow); });

//create line for hi events threshold
var hithreshold = d3.svg.line() 
    //.interpolate("monotone")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(17.11891); }); 

var tooltipdiv = d3.select("body")  //div for tooltips
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("body") //set up svg
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Set up Grid Lines
function make_x_axis() {
return d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.ticks(10)
}
function make_y_axis() {
return d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left")
.ticks(5)
}



// Get the data
d3.json("data/streamflow_json.php?watershed=ws_1", function(error, data)    
        {
        data.forEach(function(d) 
            {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.flow = +d.flow;
            });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.flow; })]);

        svg.append("g")  //grid for x axis
            .attr("class", "grid")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(make_x_axis()
                .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
                .tickFormat("")
                )

        svg.append("g")  //grid for y axis
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .call(make_y_axis()
            .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
            .tickFormat("")
            )

        svg.append("path") // Add the valueline path.
            .attr("d", valueline(data))
            .attr("class", "line");
        
        svg.append("path") // Add the hi threshold path.
            .attr("class", "hiline")
            .style("stroke", "red")
            .attr("d", hithreshold(data));

        svg.append("text")  // Chart Title
            .attr("x", (width / 2))
            .attr("y", 0 - (margin.top / 2))
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .style("font-size", "16px")
            .style("text-decoration", "underline")
            .text("Hubbard Brook Stream Flow");

        svg.append("g") // Add the X Axis
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
        
        svg.append("text") // text label for the x axis
            .attr("x", width / 2 )
            .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Date");
        
        svg.append("g") // Add the Y Axis
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
        
        svg.append("text")   // text for Y axis
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
            .attr("x", 0 - (height / 2))
            .attr("dy", "1em")
            .style("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text("Stream Flow (mm)");

        svg.selectAll("circle")  // add value dots, sized & colored
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("circle")
            //.attr("class", "dot")
            .attr("r", function(d) {
                if (d.flow > 17.11891) {return 3} 
                else if (d.flow < 0.01) { return 3 } 
                else {return 1} 
                ;}) 
            .style("fill", function(d) { 
                if (d.flow > 17.11891) {return "red"} 
                if (d.flow < 0.01) {return "yellow"} 
                else { return "black" } 
                ;}) 
            //.attr("d", tooltipdot(data))
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.flow); })
            .on("mouseover", function(d) {
                tooltipdiv.transition()
                .duration(200)
                .style("opacity", .9);
                tooltipdiv.html(formatTime(d.date) + "<br/>" + d.flow)
                .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
                })
            .on("mouseout", function(d) {
                tooltipdiv.transition()
                .duration(500)
                .style("opacity", 0);
                });
});

function updateData(value) {
//Get the data again
    d3.json("data/streamflow_json.php?watershed="+value, function(error, data)  
        {
        data.forEach(function(d) 
            {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.flow = +d.flow;
            });
    
        // Scale the range of the data again
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.flow; })]);

        // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
        var svg = d3.select("body").transition();
        // Make the changes
        svg.select(".line") // change the value line
            .duration(1750)
            .attr("d", valueline(data));
        svg.select(".hiline") // change the hithreshold line
            .duration(2750)
            .attr("d", hithreshold(data));
        /*svg.select(".circle") // change the dot
            .duration(750)
            .attr("d", tooltipdot(data));*/
        svg.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
            .duration(2750)
            .call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
            .duration(2750)
            .call(yAxis);
        });
    };

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: So you are trying to load all the data at once? JSON would be a better choice than CSV for this as you can nest arbitrarily. That is, you could simply have a map at the top level with the watershed names and underneath each the respective data.

Comment: Hi Lars, I'm now using a json file instead of csv as you suggest, but I'm just loading the whole thing at once... are you suggesting there is  smarter way to load it?  For example load data & ws_1 first, as that's the default viz?  Here's my first couple lines of json: 'code'[{"date":"1990-08-24","ws_1":"0.194","ws_2":"0.118","ws_3":"0.163","ws_4":"0.246","ws_5":"0.481","ws_6":"0.310","ws_7":"0.200","ws_8":"0.242","ws_9":"-99"},{"date":"1990-01-01","ws_1":"1.470","ws_2":"2.225","ws_3":"2.160","ws_4":"2.139","ws_5":"2.336","ws_6":"2.002","ws_7":"1.102","ws_8":"0.739","ws_9":"-99"}, etc.

Comment: You can certainly load everything at once if that isn't too slow for you.

Answer (score 0):

d3 can process the raw csv without requiring any server side formating:

```
//global variable to hold data
var csv;

// Get the data
d3.csv("data/streamflow_json.php?watershed", function(error, result){
        csv = result;
        var data = [];
        csv.forEach(function(d){
            data.push({flow: +d['ws_1'], date: parseDate(d.date)});
         });

         //ect
});
```

Since the data is stored in the csv variable, we can use it without querying the server again:

```
function updateData(value) {
        var data = [];
        csv.forEach(function(d){
            data.push({flow: +d[value], date: parseDate(d.date)});
         });

         //ect
}
```

Comment: I still can't get the dots to move along with the transition-- I am also having this problem with another bar chart where the user is selecting variables from a combo box.  Obviously bars & dots need some different formatting to get them to update in this context-- any ideas?